Memoized map of elements still re-renders if each element accepts children
I have the code and I have an issue with redundant re-rendering. Re-rendering is caused each time for all posts when I add the comment for one of them (expected: only one post should be re-rendered). My code:
const CommentForm = React.memo(({ addComment }: ICommentFormProps) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleAddComment = () => {
        addComment(inputValue);
        setInputValue("");
    };

    console.log("RENDER COMMENT FORM");

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <button onClick={handleAddComment}>Add Comment</button>
        </div>
    );
});

const Post = React.memo(({ addComment, comments, text, id }: IPostProps) => {
    console.log("RENDER POST");

    const commentsElements = useMemo(() => comments.map(comment => (
        <Comment key={comment.id}>
            <span>{comment.text}</span>
        </Comment>
    )), [comments]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.post}>
            <span>{text}</span>
            <CommentForm addComment={(text) => addComment(text, id)} />
            {commentsElements}
        </div>
    );
});

const Comment = React.memo(({ children }: ICommentProps) => {
    console.log("RENDER COMMENT");
    return (
        <div className={styles.comment}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
});

const PostForm = ({ addPost }: IPostFormProps) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleAddPost = () => {
        addPost(inputValue);
    };

    console.log("RENDER POST FORM");

    return (
        <div className={styles.form}>
            <div><textarea value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange}/></div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleAddPost}>Add Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

type Action = { type: "ADD_POST", text: string } | { type: "ADD_COMMENT", text: string, post_id: string };

const postsReducer = (state: IPost[], action: Action): IPost[] => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_POST": {
            return [...state, { id: v4(), text: action.text, comments: [] }]
        }

        case "ADD_COMMENT": {
            return state.map(
                post => post.id === action.post_id ?
                { ...post, comments: [
                    ...post.comments, { id: v4(), text: action.text, post_id: action.post_id }
                    ]
                } : post
        );
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};

const Feed = () => {
    const [posts, dispatch] = useReducer(postsReducer, []);

    const addPost = useCallback((text: string) => {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_POST", text });
    }, []);

    const addComment = useCallback((text: string, post_id: string) => {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_COMMENT", text, post_id });
    }, []);

    const postsElements = useMemo(() => posts.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} comments={post.comments} addComment={addComment} text={post.text} />
    )), [addComment, posts]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.feed}>
            <PostForm addPost={addPost} />
            <div className={styles.postContainer}>
                {postsElements}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

The code above works OK. But if I want to customize the post and use children instead of just text, re-rendering issue will appear. Changes I did:
// this one inside Feed component
const postsElements = useMemo(() => posts.map(post => (
    <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} comments={post.comments} addComment={addComment}>
        <span>{post.text}</span>
    </Post>
)), [addComment, posts]);


// and this is how Post component was changed
const Post = React.memo(({ addComment, comments, children, id }: IPostProps) => {
    console.log("RENDER POST");

    const commentsElements = useMemo(() => comments.map(comment => (
        <Comment key={comment.id}>
            <span>{comment.text}</span>
        </Comment>
    )), [comments]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.post}>
            {children}
            <CommentForm addComment={(text) => addComment(text, id)} />
            {commentsElements}
        </div>
    );
});

From my understanding, this happens because children appears to be a new object on each Post render. But it is not clear why this happens since I use React.memo to wrap the children.
Could somebody explain what am I doing wrong and why this behavior happens ? My React version: 18.3.1

Using isEqual from lodash solved the issue:
const Post = React.memo(({ addComment, comments, children, id }: IPostProps) => {
    console.log("RENDER POST");

    const commentsElements = useMemo(() => comments.map(comment => (
        <Comment key={comment.id}>
            <span>{comment.text}</span>
        </Comment>
    )), [comments]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.post}>
            {children}
            <CommentForm addComment={(text) => addComment(text, id)} />
            {commentsElements}
        </div>
    );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => isEqual(prevProps, nextProps));

Probably there another solutions are possible ?
